# Unable to get 3 equal-width columns in a .ui.page.grid

Tags: css, semantic-ui

I am really struggling with getting 3 columns inside a page layout.

I am only using the semantic CSS, no CSS of my own for now. I am just trying to wrap my head around the grid stuff.

This is my complete body content:

```
    <div class="ui page grid">
      <header class="sixteen wide column">
        <div class="ui segment">Header text.</div>
      </header>
      <div class="ui divided grid">
        <div class="eight wide column">
          <div class="ui segment">Left text</div>
        </div>
        <div class="eight wide column">
          <div class="ui segment">Right text</div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="ui three column grid">
        <div class="column">
          <div class="ui segment">1</div>
        </div>
        <div class="column">
          <div class="ui segment">2</div>
        </div>
        <div class="column">
          <div class="ui segment">3</div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <footer class="sixteen wide column">
        <div class="ui segment">Footer text.</div>
      </footer>
    </div>
```

I understand how to get a full width column — that's verbose but it works.

I also am able to get 2 half-width columns using .sixteen.wide.column elements.

But since 16 is not dividable by 3, I am trying to use this to obtain 3 columns:

```
      <div class="ui three column grid">
        <div class="column">
          <div class="ui segment">1</div>
        </div>
        <div class="column">
          <div class="ui segment">2</div>
        </div>
        <div class="column">
          <div class="ui segment">3</div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

That code above is lifted from this documentation page: http://semantic-ui.com/collections/grid.html

I get this, alas:

[image: welcome shopify ui elements generator 2014-03-16 15-08-56 2014-03-16 15-09-05]

It seems that the width issue comes from this CSS:

```
 .ui.grid > .column, .ui.grid > .row > .column {
   width: 6.25%;
 }
```

No I need an additional class anywhere, or some additional markup?

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

Here you go:

```
<div class="ui three column grid">
  <div class="column">
    Content
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    Content
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    Content
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem!

Its done this way:

```
    <div class="ui divided grid stackable">

        <div class="three column row">

         <div class="column wide"> 
          <p> Your stuff here </p>
         </div>

         <div class="column wide">
         <p> Your stuff here </p>
         </div>

         <div class="column wide">
          <p> Your stuff here </p>
         </div>

        </div>

   </div>
```

Comment: Also upon looking at all your code above. Your using too many Grids, more than needs be.  Try using rows with an ID instead of grids, then you can define the row height in the css via the ID. Much better for page flow!